# Hypergeometric2F1 hangs on certain numeric input with Mathematica 10

Tags: bugs, numerics, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.1.0**

---

This works fine:

```
Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][1, 0, 2,  I/10^15 + 447.57809534442]
```

and gives `-5.08798 + 3.13457 I` within tiny milliseconds as expected. However, with this input

```
Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][1, 0, 2,  I/10^15 + 447.578095344423]
```

Mathematica hangs for several minutes, so I have no enough patience to wait for the answer. What is the reason and how I can overcome this behaviour?

I use Mathematica 10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015). Just checked this example with Mathematica 8 on Linux and all works fine, so this issue is version/OS specific.

Comment: The problem is present also on 11.0.

Comment: Yes, the problem is present on 11.0.0 under Windows

Comment: And I just checked that the problem is present in Wolfram Cloud

Comment: It works in 5.2, tho.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised it doesn't take the derivative symbolically first.  `Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][1, 0, 2, x]` is equal to `1 - Log[1 - x] + Log[1 - x]/x`.

Comment: Bug fixed in 11.1.0

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(*  "11.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"  *)

Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][1, 0, 2, 
  I/10^15 + 447.57809534442] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.065291, -5.08798 + 3.13457 I}  *)
```

For the second case, use arbitrary-precision rather than machine precision

```
Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][1, 0, 2, 
  I/10^15 + 447.578095344423`15] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.048323, -5.0879817774139 + 3.1345735597461 I}  *)
```

Comment: But how I can setup Mathematica to use arbitrary-precision rather than machine precision automatically? I can't just insert "`15" manually to each number that appears in my program and external libraries that I use.

Comment: @StanislavPoslavsky As a fix, it should be enough to do the conversion before calling this function. Computing ``x * 1`15`` should do it. I don't know how to convert back to machine-precision though.